# Counting unique dates by Id in a data frame

Tags: r, group-by, unique

Imagine I have measurements of 5 participants, performed on different days. The number of measurements differs between the participants. 
I would like to know at how many days measurements were performed for every participant

Let's say I have the following data frame (see image):

view(df)

```
Id  Date
1   1-2-2019
1   2-2-2019
2   5-2-2019
2   5-2-2019
3   8-2-2019
4   7-2-2019
5   9-2-2019
5   1-3-2019
5   11-4-2019
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
Id  Days
1   2
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   3
```

I have tried something like  `length(unique(df$date), by="Id")`

Comment: Separate days into different table.

Comment: `aggregate(Date~Id, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!!